# XMLHTTP Post not working

Tags: javascript, post, get, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

I am trying to get the PDF file in to response using XMLHTTP and the post the response using XMLHTTP get. Get part works well but the Post part does not get the response.

```
   var Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
Req.open("POST",'http://192.168.56.103/API/Twebservice.asmx/Updatepdf', false);
Req.onload = function (oEvent) {
  // Uploaded.


var blob = function(){var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
 xhr.open("GET", "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf",true);
 xhr.send();

 if (xhr.status === 200) { 
 var test=xhr.responseText;//console.log(test)

 }} }
//GetPDF();
Req.send(blob());
```

Hope some one can help.

Comment: `Req.send(blob());` makes no sense. You are actually doing `Req.send(undefined);` What do you think blob() is doing?

Comment: This was just me trying but i think due to async nature ...i cannot get the response text in to a variable

Comment: So you make the call after you get the data back, but the issue you will face in your code is same origin policy

Comment: I have access to both servers...that URL to PDF file is just for test. I could not get the data in to the response. The post callgets triggered with out any data.

Comment: You are treatng an asynchrouns call as synchronous. The blob call needs an onload and inside the onload you call the other Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the call as asynchronous. Call the second after the first is done.

```
function firstCall() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open("GET", "path1", true); 
  xhr.onload = function () {
    secondCall(xhr.responseText);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
      console.error("Error", xhr.statusText);
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function secondCall(data) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open("POST", "path2", true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log("done");    
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
      console.error("Error", xhr.statusText);
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Epascarello ...that fixed it .Now i know where I was going wrong.